# Combining add_loss with keras.losses in multioutput models using intermediate outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Previously in another post ([Keras multioutput custom loss with intermediate layers output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526604/keras-multioutput-custom-loss-with-intermediate-layers-output)) I discussed the problem I was having. Finally, this problem was fixed in this way:

```
def MyLoss(true1, true2, out1, out2, out3):
    loss1 = tf.keras.losses.someloss1(out1, true1)
    loss2 = tf.keras.losses.someloss2(out2, true2)
    loss3 = tf.keras.losses.someloss3(out2, out3)
    loss = loss1 + loss2 + loss3
    return loss

input1 = Input(shape=input1_shape)
input2 = Input(shape=input2_shape)

# do not take into account the notation, only the idea
output1 = Submodel1()([input1,input2]) 
output2 = Submodel2()(output1)
output3 = Sumbodel3()(output1)

true1 = Input(shape=true1shape)
true2 = Input(shape=true2shape)

model = Model([input1,input2,true1,true2], [output1,output2,output3])
model.add_loss(MyLoss(true1, true2, output1, output2, output3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None)

model.fit(x=[input1 ,input2 ,true1,true2], y=None, epochs=n_epochs)
```

In that problem, all the losses I used were keras losses (i.e. `tf.keras.losss.someloss`) but now I want to add a couple more losses and I want to combine custom losses with keras losses. That is, now I have this scheme:

[image]

For adding these two losses, which are **SSIM** losses, I have tried this:

```
def SSIMLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, 1.0))

def MyLoss(true1, true2, out1, out2, out3):
    loss1 = tf.keras.losses.someloss1(out1, true1)
    customloss1 = SSIMLoss(out1,true1)
    loss2 = tf.keras.losses.someloss2(out2, true2)
    loss3 = tf.keras.losses.someloss3(out2, out3)
    customloss2 = SSIMLoss(out2,out3)
    loss = loss1 + loss2 + loss3 + customloss1 + customloss2
    return loss
```

But I get this error:

`` OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function. ``

I have tried decorating the function with `@tf.function` but I get this error:

`_SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'input_43:0' shape=(None, 128, 128, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'conv2d_109/Sigmoid:0' shape=(None, 128, 128, 1) dtype=float32>]`

I have found this (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32127) about combining keras losses with `add_loss`, maybe this is the problem, but I don´t know how to fix it.

Comment: Would you please give some feedback on the given answer?

Comment: Hi @M.Innat, yes, sorry. I have been a bit busy these days and I have not been able to check your solution. I've started now and it seems to be working, although I'm getting other errors unrelated to this one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your above errors in `TF 2.3`. But in `TF 2.4` and nightly `TF 2.6`, there was **no such issue**, but when I tried to **plot the model** I got another error, though **no issue** with the **`model. summary()`** and also training with **`.fit`**. However, if the eager mode is disabled, then there wouldn't be an issue with `TF 2.3 / 2.4`.

---

#### Details

In `TF 2.3`, I can reproduce your issue same shown below. To resolve this, just **disable the eager mode** showed above.

In `TF 2.4` / `TF Nightly 2.6`, I didn't need to disable the eager mode. The model was compiled fine and train as expected. But the only issue occurs when I tried to plot the model, it gave the following error

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model)
....
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no 
attribute '_keras_history'
```

This issue caused for `1-..` expression in the `SSIMLoss` method; something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889187/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-keras-history).
But again, by **disabling the eager mode**, it resolves anyway. However, in general, it's better to upgrade to `TF 2.4`.

---

#### Code Examples

Here I will show you a dummy example that probably similar to your training pipelines. In this example, we have one input (`28, 28, 3`) and three outputs (`28, 28, 3`).

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Model 
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

# tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.executing_eagerly())
2.4.1
True
```

**Custom loss functions.**

```
def SSIMLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, 1.0))

def MyLoss(true1, true2, out1, out2, out3):
    loss1 = tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(out1, true1)
    loss2 = tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(out2, true2)
    loss3 = tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(out2, out3)
    customloss1 = SSIMLoss(true1, out1)
    customloss2 = SSIMLoss(out2, out3)

    loss = loss1 + loss2 + loss3 + customloss1 + customloss2
    return loss
```

**Data**

```
imgA = tf.random.uniform([10, 28, 28, 3], minval=0, maxval=256)
tarA = np.random.randn(10, 28, 28, 3)
tarB = np.random.randn(10, 28, 28, 3)
```

**Model**

A model with one input and three outputs.

```
input  = Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
middle = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same')(input)

outputA = Dense(3, activation='relu')(middle)
outputB = Dense(3, activation='selu')(middle)
outputC = Dense(3, activation='elu')(middle)

target_inputA = Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
target_inputB = Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))

model = Model([input, target_inputA, target_inputB], 
              [outputA, outputB, outputC])

model.add_loss(MyLoss(target_inputA, target_inputB, 
                      outputA, outputB, outputC))

# tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model) # disable eager mode 
model.summary()
```

**Compile and Run**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None)
model.fit([imgA, tarA, tarB], steps_per_epoch=5)

5/5 [==============================] - 2s 20ms/step - loss: 1.4338
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7efde188d450>
```

Comment: Hi @M.Innat. I have been working with your solution on TF 2.3 disabling eager and TF 2.4 without disabling it. Both seem to work but in TF 2.4 an epoch takes 5 hours to execute whereas in TF 2.3 takes 5 minutes (which is too much for my case). However, in TF 2.4 the GPU volatile utility is 0%, so I guess I am not using the GPU.

Comment: It's a known issue that, the eager mode is slow compare to graph mode. Check this [question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67383458/why-is-this-tensorflow-training-taking-so-long/67420239#comment119394482_67420239) regarding this issue. Also, if possible, try to run your code with the latest `tf 2.5` and also the nightly package to see how it goes.

Comment: hello @M.Innat,  I am working on a problem similar to this and I want to use loss_weights with Loss Weights Modifier after certain epochs using keras.callbacks. For example loss weights for this model are: `outputA = LW1, outputB = LW2, outputC= LW3`. If I use loss functions in the model.compile, then I can simply pass loss_weights like loss_weights=[LW1, LW2, LW3]. Can I define LW1, LW2, LW3 as variable and use it inside Custom Loss function?

Comment: It might be possible. Please ask a separate questions with details.

Comment: Hello @M.Innat I have made a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74469746/keras-multioutput-classifier-with-a-custom-loss-function-that-includes-additiona). Will really appreciate your comments regarding this.